# Proper Encoding for chines character from NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding, nsstring

Please help me i'm using below code to get file name.
Here i'm getting `NSString` from `NSData` where `multipartData` is `NSMutableArray` which contain `NSData`.

```
NSString* postInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[[multipartData objectAtIndex:1] bytes] length:[[multipartData objectAtIndex:1] length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I'm getting string like:

```
Printing description of postInfo:

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="??:??.PNG"
```

But It should be like:

```
Printing description of postInfo:

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="华语/華語.PNG"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the server doesn't encode the response using UTF-8, but probably [another Chinese-only encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding). You need to use the `Content-Type` header to detect which encoding it is, and then find the appropriate `NSStringEncoding` using the following code;

```
// set charset to the MIME charset you get from the server
CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)(charset)));
```

Here is a detailed answer:

```
// getting the Content-Type header (e.g. "application/json; charset=utf-8")
NSString* header = [[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];

// getting the MIME type
NSString* charset = nil;
NSArray* contentTypeParts = [header componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSInteger i = 0;
for (NSString* part in contentTypeParts) {
    // ignoring first loop (e.g. "application/json")
    if (i > 0) {
        NSArray* partComponents = [part componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        if ([partComponents count] == 2 && [@"charset" isEqualToString:[[partComponents objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]]) {
            charset = [[partComponents objectAtIndex:1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            break;
        }
    }
    i++;
}

// converting the MIME type to NSStringEncoding
NSStringEncoding stringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding; // default to UTF8
if (charset) {
    stringEncoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)(charset)));
}

// finally you can convert your string properly!
NSString* postInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[[multipartData objectAtIndex:1] bytes] length:[[multipartData objectAtIndex:1] length] encoding:stringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but what i have to pass as in "response"?
FYI : multipartData is my array which contain NSData.

Comment: All depends on which HTTP library you're using. I assumed you were using `NSURLConnection`, and you were getting back an `NSHTTPURLResponse` object. Just set the `header` to your response `Content-Type` header.